# How to visualize the regression line on a Multivariate Polynomial Regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So I have this code and I'm getting a good r score for my SGD model. The only thing that's left for me to do is to visualize the regression line and I have no idea how. Here's my code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

X_F1, y_F1 = make_friedman1(n_samples = 100,
                           n_features = 7, random_state=0)
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_train_scale = poly.fit_transform(X_F1)
poly.fit(X_train_scale,y_F1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_train_scale,y_F1, random_state=0)
PolyReg = SGDRegressor(alpha=0.001,max_iter=100000).fit(X_train,y_train)
print ("Intercept for the Polynomial model ",PolyReg.intercept_)
print ("Coefficents for the Polynomial model ",PolyReg.coef_)
print ("R-squared Score (training) = ",PolyReg.score(X_train,y_train))
print ("R-squared Score (test) = ",PolyReg.score(X_test,y_test))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines?

```
x = X_test
y = `PolyReg.coef_ * x + PolyReg.intercept_
plt.plot(x, y, '-')
plt.show()
```

substitute the `x` and `y` values according to what you want to see.
You may also add data points on the same plot, by something like:

```
plt.plot(x, y_test, ".")
```

Comment: Thanks alot! But I noticed when I plot the regression line along with my datasets, all points go above the line. I'm a beginner at python so I don't know what causes this

Comment: Well, I meant to help how to plot. But understanding of the data is on your side ;-) I mean: substitute `x` and `y` with whatever you want to plot, e.g. maybe you want to plot the train data, not test. Maybe there is a bug in the learning procedure itself; I relied on what you wrote that the coefficient is good. In any case, now as you are able to plot, it should be helpful to understand what happens.